# Orion Context Broker crashes

Tags: fiware-orion

We have an Orion instance which crashes about once each day or two.

In `/var/log/contextBroker/contextBroker-service.out` I have found:

```
log directory: '/var/log/contextBroker'
*** glibc detected *** /usr/bin/contextBroker: corrupted double-linked list: 0x00007f0ed92e3f70 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x75f4e)[0x7f0eecdeaf4e]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x763d3)[0x7f0eecdeb3d3]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x78c88)[0x7f0eecdedc88]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSsD1Ev+0x39)[0x7f0eed6404c9]
/usr/bin/contextBroker(_Z9jsonParseP14ConnectionInfoPKcRKSsP8JsonNodeP9ParseData+0x539)[0x56fb99]
/usr/bin/contextBroker(_Z9jsonTreatPKcP14ConnectionInfoP9ParseData11RequestTypeRKSsPP11JsonRequest+0x17d)[0x56cf0d]
/usr/bin/contextBroker(_Z12payloadParseP14ConnectionInfoP9ParseDataP11RestServicePP10XmlRequestPP11JsonRequestP18JsonDelayedReleaseRSt6vectorISsSaISsEE+0x3f2)[0x564012]
/usr/bin/contextBroker(_Z11restServiceP14ConnectionInfoP11RestService+0x126c)[0x5654bc]
/usr/bin/contextBroker[0x55cbb6]
/usr/bin/contextBroker[0x55f987]
/usr/lib64/libmicrohttpd.so.10(+0x5599)[0x7f0eee1cf599]
/usr/lib64/libmicrohttpd.so.10(MHD_connection_handle_idle+0x518)[0x7f0eee1d0078]
/usr/lib64/libmicrohttpd.so.10(+0xc3c8)[0x7f0eee1d63c8]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7a51)[0x7f0eec957a51]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f0eece5d93d]
```

And in `/var/log/contextBroker/contextBroker-service.out.old` the following:

```
log directory: '/var/log/contextBroker'
*** glibc detected *** /usr/bin/contextBroker: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00007fe6d4262110 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x75f4e)[0x7fe6e8e9cf4e]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x78cf0)[0x7fe6e8e9fcf0]
/usr/bin/contextBroker(_ZN20ContextElementVector7releaseEv+0x2fa)[0x5f4a4a]
/usr/bin/contextBroker(_Z17postUpdateContextP14ConnectionInfoiRSt6vectorISsSaISsEEP9ParseDatab+0x1472)[0x4d6692]
/usr/bin/contextBroker(_Z11restServiceP14ConnectionInfoP11RestService+0x6d6)[0x564926]
/usr/bin/contextBroker[0x55cbb6]
/usr/bin/contextBroker[0x55f987]
/usr/lib64/libmicrohttpd.so.10(+0x5599)[0x7fe6ea281599]
/usr/lib64/libmicrohttpd.so.10(MHD_connection_handle_idle+0x518)[0x7fe6ea282078]
/usr/lib64/libmicrohttpd.so.10(+0xc3c8)[0x7fe6ea2883c8]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7a51)[0x7fe6e8a09a51]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fe6e8f0f93d]
```

Data is sent to the Orion in batches each 5 minutes:

- a request with around 500 `contextElements`
- a request with around 10 `contextElements`
- a request with a single `contextElements`

Orion has only 2 subscriptions (AFAIK) which send the data to Proton-CEP.

The Orion version is:

```
[centos@orion ~]$ /usr/bin/contextBroker --version
0.25.0 (git version: a8cf800d4e9fdd7b4293a886490c40309a5bb58c)
Copyright 2013-2015 Telefonica Investigacion y Desarrollo, S.A.U
```

Is there anything we can do to debug the issue?

Comment: How much RAM memory and CPU use the system in which CB is running? In additon, is there any other process with CPU/memory footprint running in the same system (e.g. Tomcat, JBoss, some Node.js processes, etc.)?

Comment: @fgalan 2GB RAM, 1vCPU, 20GB HDD. It's based on an image provided in the FIWARE LAB, so other than Orion, nothing else is running in that VM.

Comment: That seems to be below the recommended thresholds at http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/admin/diagnosis/index.html#resource-availability. Could you test with 2 vCPU and 4GB RAM just to see how it goes, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account user inputs, Orion seems to be running below the recommended CPU and RAM thresholds (see [recomendations](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/admin/diagnosis/index.html#resource-availability)). Thus, probably with more resources (e.g. 2 vCPU and 4GM RAM) it run better, specially if MongoDB runs in the same machine that Orion (MongoDB is known to be a memory-intensive process).